TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect') when using a locally linked Excalidraw package in React
I'm attempting to use the Excalidraw library as a locally linked package in my React application. After setting up the package with yarn link, I imported Excalidraw into my component:
import { Excalidraw } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw";
However, when I run my app, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
at useEffect (react.development.js:1634:1)
at ExcalidrawBase (index.tsx:84:1)
...

I’ve ensured that both my app and the Excalidraw package are using React 18.3.1. The error seems related to mismatched React versions or an issue with how the package is built. I've also tried updating the build script to externalize React and ReactDOM, but the error persists.
What could be causing this useEffect error, and how can I resolve it?

something in your code is null where it's not expected to be null - anything in the error stack trace that points to your code?

I tried reducing my code to the bare minimum by only importing the Excalidraw component, like this:
import {Excalidraw} from '@excalidraw/excalidraw';

export default function App() {
  return (
  <div>
    <Excalidraw />
  </div>
  );
}```
but still am getting ```Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')```

@JaromandaX Could there be another underlying issue causing this, possibly related to how the package is being built or linked?

Hi @JaromandaX I have fixed the issue. We need to symlink the react and react-dom from react app to excalidraw and rebuild the excalidraw package solves the issue. for more info I have replied in github issue.

So to resolve the

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect') error.

I have created a symlink for my apps react and react-dom,
In my D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw
D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw>npm link ../../../MyReactApp/node_modules/react

D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw>npm link ../../../MyReactApp/node_modules/react-dom

D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw>yarn build:esm
yarn run v1.22.22
$ node ../../scripts/buildPackage.js && yarn gen:types
$ tsc
Done in 23.43s.

D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw>yarn postbuild
yarn run v1.22.22
$ node fix-imports.mjs
Done in 0.28s.

After this, I can see excalidraw imported into my react app but still have a CSS issue.
GET https://unpkg.com/@excalidraw/excalidraw@0.17.6/dist/prod/CascadiaCode-Regular-TMZI7IJ5.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So for this, I have imported the CSS directly into my react app where Excalidraw is imported.
import { Excalidraw } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw";
import "@excalidraw/excalidraw/index.css";

Now I am able to use the excalidraw as a local package using npm link :). For any changes in excalidraw to reflect in my react app, each time I need to rebuild the package.
 D:\Project\excalidraw\packages\excalidraw>yarn build:esm

For more on the steps please check github.
